# How do I not allow a website containing mine from accessing page data

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have a login on my page but I don't want a website who has my page embedded in an iframe to be able to access the username and password input's, or anything for that matter.

I don't want to block iFrames all together because my site only runs in parts of pages.

Comment: You don't need to do anything. That's part of browser security model.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers respond to the "Same-origin policy" that avoids this kind of thing. The only thing you have to do is to be sure that the site which embed your website is from another domain name.

See [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) on MDN